# Generating a unique number for each user & encrypting the data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am creating a iPod app which will on multiple devices. For each user login on my app, I want to create a unique number on client to track the session as well as service calls within this session. This tracking will happen on my server where I could know all the service calls made by the client for a particular session.

I am planning to create a hash which is made up of some unique login session ID created on client and timestamp and then hashed with some fixed number.

Is there any easy mechanism to generate a unique number on IOS and then some hash (encryption) algorithm which could be used on my server side to decypher to get the original string. My server will be in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CFUUID`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFUUIDRef/Reference/reference.html)s, unique 128-bit integers, that can be created using `CFUUIDCreate`. They already incorporates timestamp info, so you may be able to use `UUID`s as your session IDs without additional timestamps. If you use `SSL` for yor connection to the server, you do not need to do any additional encryption either.

Comment: Ok. One question - Will this CFUUID be unique for each login within my app from within the same device. I want a unique number each time user logs out and logs in in the application from the same device?

Comment: Every time CFUUID creates unique number, other things depend only on your own implementation.

Comment: @Abhinav This number will change every time you call `CFUUIDCreate`, regardless of the user, the device, or anything else. You wouldn't get the same number twice. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) has a good article explaining how this "magic" works.